# Which cables should I use to connect a 4090 nvidia GPU to my PSU in a z790 MoBo?

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, power-supply, pcie, cable

Asus ROG builder newbie here.

I'm building my first top setup based on the Asus ROG - Eva 02 edition, I read all the manuals already and got everything pluged in. I had not used it yet because I want to be sure everything's ok, so I have a couple of questions regarding to GPU - PSU connections:

- The 4090 GPU came with this 4x8-pin to 12vhpwr cable and I used the PCIe cables to connect the PSU (1200W Thor edition), but the PSU came with this 2x8-pin to 16-pin cable which I'm not using. I saw in youtube someone using it instead of the default GPU cable. Which one should I use? would this make a difference?
- The MoBo came with this pd_12v_pwr slot which, based on the manual, could provide the PCIe bus a 60W capacity instead of the 27W default one. Also helping the USB-C to provide faster charge to a phone. I connected a PSU 8-pin PCIe cable (using just 6 pins ofc) but I want to know if you guys think this would affect GPU performance in any way? (choosing connecting the cable or not)

TIA, best regards

Comment: Hi Raa, welcome to Hardware Recs! This site is for questions regarding acquiring *new* hardware; for help with existing hardware, you should try superuser.com. That said: 1. You'll want to avoid the adapter and use the 12VHPR cable included with your PSU; the adapter is intended for PSUs that don't have such a cable, and has been known to come loose and cause electrical issues on some occasions. 2. It can help stabilize voltage fluctuations, especially during overclocking, which can help with performance; however, outside of overclocking, it's unlikely to be important. It won't hurt though.